# LINQ where clause

Tags: linq, where-clause

I have the following linq query

```
var ret = from u in MenuHeaders
   .Include("MenuHeaderItems.MenuItem")                 
   select u;
```

I need to select ONLY menu headers which exist for certain users, which belong to a certain role given a user id.

So, the relational path would be something like this...

```
MenuHeader    RoleMenuHeaders   Roles      UserRoles   Users
----------    ---------------   -----      ---------   -----
ID        <---MenuHeaderID  |-> ID <---|   UserID----->ID
              RoleID -------|          |-- RoleID
```

How do I get my above query to only return MenuHeaders where UserID=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using LINQ to Entities, this relationship is probably automatically mapped via properties, and (assuming these are many-to-many relationships, as they appear to be in the schema you show) you can take advantage of the Any operator:

```
var ret = from mh in MenuHeaders.Include("MenuHeaderItems.MenuItem")      
   where mh.Roles.Any(r => r.Users.Any(u => u.UserId == 1))
   select mh;
```

Comment: `.Include()` is a Linq-to-Entities method, so this looks correct

Comment: Dude. I beat Jon Skeet. I have attained Nirvana. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it with a join:

```
var ret = from mh in MenuHeaders.Include("MenuHeaderItems.MenuItem")
          join ur in UserRoles on mh.RoleID equals u.RoleID
          where ur.UserID == 1
          select mh;
```

(I don't know whether you need `Include("UserRoles.UserRole")` or anything like that. I don't know which LINQ provider you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a where clause that references a joined table modifies the resultant query and invalidates the Include.

Check this out.
[How to make an Include really include.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alexj/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include)